# Redirect on custom page after registration in magento2

Tags: frontend, magento2

I want to redirect on my custom page when customer create a new account successfully. How to do it? Please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *In the future, please note that it would be better to ask this kind of question in the **[Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)***.

Although, to answer your question, just add this line to your overwrite class:

`$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('path/to/file'));`

Replace `path/to/file` with the path to which you would like customers to be redirected to.